# Regular expression that accepts tokens of three or more alphabetical characters

Tags: python, regex, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to build a TFIDVectorizer that only accepts tokens of 3 or more **alphabetical** characters using `TFIdfVectorizer(token_pattern="(?u)\\b\\D\\D\\D+\\b")`

But it doesn't behave correctly, I know `token_pattern="(?u)\\b\\w\\w\\w+\\b"` accepts tokens of 3 or more **alphanumerical** characters, so I just don't understand why the former is not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Three  or more letters is `token_pattern="[^\W\d_]{3,}"` or `token_pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in using the `\D` metacharacter, as it's actually for matching any **non-digit** character, rather than any **alphabetical** character. From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#:%7E:text=0%2D9%5D.-,%5CD,Matches%20any%20character%20which%20is%20not%20a%20decimal%20digit,-.%20This%20is%20the):
[image]

You can go instead with:

```py
token_pattern="(?i)[a-z]{3,}"
```

Explanation:

- `(?i)` — inline flag to make matching case-insensitive,
- `[a-z]` — matches any Latin letter,
- `{3,}` — makes the previous *token* match three or more times (greedily, i.e., as many times as possible).

I hope this answers your question. :)